Generating a single fast pulse with controlled duration
I am new to Raspberry Pi IO pins. I want to generate a single pulse with a pulse duration between 100-1000 ns, I want the pulse duration to be stable in the range of 10's ns, and I would like to control the pulse duration in steps of 100's ns. Is such thing possible with a Raspberry Pi 4?
A very quick test with this code:
from time import sleep

def generate_pulse(pin_number:int):
    GPIO.output(N_PIN_OUTPUT, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(N_PIN_OUTPUT, GPIO.LOW)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_PIN_OUTPUT = 37

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Configure to use numbering from the RPi connector.
    GPIO.setup(N_PIN_OUTPUT, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO 26 (pin 37 in the connector) as output.

    while True:
        generate_pulse(N_PIN_OUTPUT)
        sleep(.1)

makes me believe that hardware-wise it may be possible, as I am getting a pulse of approximately 1000 ns duration with fluctuations in the order of 500 ns.
Are there dedicated functions or libraries for this?

After doing some research I wrote this code:
import pigpio # https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio
from time import sleep

def generate_one_pulse(pulse_duration):
    PWM_FREQ = int(1e3) # PWMfreq 1-125e6, http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#PWMfreq
    PIN = 12 # pin GPIO 12, pint 32 in the connector.

    max_pulse_duration = PWM_FREQ**-1/2

    if pulse_duration > max_pulse_duration:
        raise RuntimeError(f'Pulse duration cannot be higher than {max_pulse_duration:.2e}, received {pulse_duration:.2e}. ')

    duty_cycle = 1e6*pulse_duration*PWM_FREQ # The factor `1e6` comes from http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#PWMduty

    PI = pigpio.pi()
    PI.hardware_PWM(PIN, PWM_FREQ, int(duty_cycle))
    sleep(1/PWM_FREQ/2) # Wait half a duty cycle, before setting PWM 0. We have faith that the program will make it, but this could fail if the processor is too busy.
    PI.hardware_PWM(PIN, PWM_FREQ, 0) # The only way I found so far of stopping the PWM, setting a duty cycle of 0.

while True:
    generate_one_pulse(float(input('Pulse duration? (ns) '))*1e-9)

It is capable of generating single sub-nanosecond pulses with a resolution of 1 nanosecond.

Generating repeatable software only driven signals within a real time operating system is difficult. Your program is only 1 of perhaps 100s of programs running simultaneously on the Raspberry Pi. For the same reason, it is difficult to drive addressable LEDs directly from a Raspberry Pi. Or drive servo motors w/o some jitter.
Keep in mind, if your program crashes, the operating system does not. This is accomplished by not giving your program total control of the Raspbery Pi. And, consequently, not allowing your program to dependably create precisely timed signals.
That said,there are open source efforts which try to create precisely times signal from a Raspberry Pi. This project tries to control addressable LED and this project tries to control servo motors. Perhaps there use techniques which can be reused in your project. There may be other and better project. These projects were picked because they claim to use the PWM hardware that is part of some if not all Raspberry Pi processors. In very simple terms, it may be possible to set up the processor's PWM hardware and allow the hardware to run independent of the software.
